# UIView and nextDrawable on a multithreaded system

Tags: multithreading, metal, metalkit

I have a multithreaded application.
All the rendering is performed on a different thread than the main thread.

- The device and the different CommandQueue are created on the main thread.
- The RenderThread will create and commit new commandBuffers.
- The swap chain image are acquired on the RenderThread by calling nextDrawable on the CAMetalDrawable via the main UIWindow.

Code:

```
CAMetalLayer *layer= (CAMetalLayer*)uiView.layer; 
setRenderTarget(layer.texture)
```

This triggers a weird crash on iOS when committing an empty commandbuffer (just a simple clear operation).

```
[m_command_buffer commit];
```

[image]
[image]

Note this seems to work fine on macOS using NSView instead.
Is it something to be expected?
how should we acquire the swap chain image and call the final **[commandBuffer commit]** on a multithreaded system?

apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Cmd-Submiss/Cmd-Submiss.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH3-SW6

At first I thought it was a memory issue but:
xcode gauge is in the green with 3gb left, I also added the *increase memory limit* permission. The crash is located when commit is called, if I comment it I can continue running my main loop.

Comment: I mean, I don't think this has anything to do with multithreading and everything to do with jetsam limits. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/identifying-high-memory-use-with-jetsam-event-reports

Comment: You are running out of memory.

Comment: xcode gauge is in the green with 3gb left, I also added the increase memory limit permission. The crash is located when commit is called, if I comment the call I am fine.

Comment: Which iPhone is it?

Comment: iphone 12 pro max

Comment: That gauge doesn't show memory used by the GPU IIRC. Bottom line is the message "Terminated due to memory issue" couldn't be more clear.

Comment: From what I can gather the memory should be shared between the CPU and GPU, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_A14, I might be missing something.

Comment: Yes it has unified memory, but I'm pretty sure that gauge doesn't show memory claimed by the GPU. I think to see full memory use, you'll need to use Instruments or Metal Frame Capture.

Comment: Also, the OS will terminate your app if it detects something funky, like excessive memory leaks - there is no guarantee it will allow you to use any amount of memory.

Comment: iPhone 12 Pro is 6 gigs, 3 gigs in Xcode is pretty high. I would suggest trying to run without Metal Capture and Metal API Validation and see if that helps, but if you are actually running out of memory, there's nothing you can do apart from using less memory. I'm not sure why the empty command buffer triggers it, but you can check if your app generates a jetsam event. If it does, then you are running out of memory and there's no two ways about it.

Comment: Sounds like GPU memory used is reported now - hasn't always been the case IIRC. Anyhow yeah continuously using 3GB of 6GB sounds like a memory crash or OOM just waiting to happen.